# Limitations on Ranger: Falconer archetype animal companion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranger, animal-companions, archetype

So I was thinking of taking a two level dip into this class and the archetype appealed to me as flavorful. 
[Falconer archetype page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/falconer)

> At 1st level, a falconer earns the trust and companionship of a bird of prey. The bird can be of any type of large hunting or scavenging bird (even a vulture). This ability functions like the druid animal companion ability (which is part of the nature bond class feature), but the falconer must take the bird animal companion, and that companion has only half the normal hit points.

However I am unsure what the limitations are on this? It mentions a "**bird of prey**" it also says it can by "**any type of large hunting or scavenging bird**" so to me that sounds like any bird of prey listed under the "bird" type for druid/ranger animal companions.

**Here is where I viewed the list of "[Birds](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Animal_companion)"**

*However* it also says, "**but the falconer must take the [bird animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Bird)**" which leaves me wondering if it is simply limited to bird or the several detailed mentions above of a bird of prey?

I am clearly unconcerned with the power of the companion in combat as this will only be a two level dip but I wanted to be sure what my limitations where regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Falconer page states:

> The bird can be of any type of large hunting or scavenging bird (even a vulture). This ability functions like the druid animal companion ability (which is part of the nature bond class feature), but the falconer must take the bird animal companion, and that companion has only half the normal hit points.

Since the system doesn't specify exactly what qualifies as a bird of prey aside from telling you it can be any kind of large hunting or scavenging bird but that it does allow you to take a vulture, The likely course of action would be that the Ranger would have access to any Bird type animal companion. So you could take an Eagle, a Falcon, a Roc, or a vulture, provided it had the Bird sub-type.

At 4th level when Ranger would normally get an animal companion, instead your animal companion would level up and would have 100% of its HP instead of the half it starts off with.

Comment: That is what I thought but someone posed this as well http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Bird (recent so I need to edit post) saying that it means THAT bird. As it says, "but the falconer must take the bird animal companion" Thoughts?

Comment: It isn't specified exactly what it means, but I take it that since the Vulture was specified and theres an entry for that on the animal companion table that it doesn't specifically mean "birds" but more loosely defines birds instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about with vulture having an entry. There are entries for Whisper Vultures and Giant Vultures.